attributeError when loading yolov5s from torch hub
I am trying to build a driver drowsiness detection model. I wanted to load in the yolov5s ultralytics implementation using torch hub but I am getting an error.
The code I wrote:
model=torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','yolov5s')
I have already loaded in ultralytics, torch,torchvision, numpy. I am getting an attributeerror like so:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:566, in load(repo_or_dir, model, source, trust_repo, force_reload, verbose, skip_validation, *args, **kwargs)
562 if source == 'github':
563     repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
564                                        verbose=verbose, skip_validation=skip_validation)
--> 566 model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
567 return model
.
.
.
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'
How do I fix ths?
I tried reinstalling the latest versions of torch and numpy but the error did not change.

Does this answer your question? module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'
